# Q: why _rvalues_ were renamed to _prvalues_? (pure rvalues)

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, rvalue, prvalue

This document appears to be the source of these changes from C++11: [n3055](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3055.pdf).

> **II. Overview of Changes**
>
> Rvalues, as currently known in the core language clauses, are renamed
>   to “**prvalues**” (“pure” rvalues).

**lvalues** meaning was not changed, but **glvalues** were introduced to cover **xvalues**.

Why not do the same for **rvalues**?!

**rvalues** meaning should have remain unchanged, but introduce **grvalues** to cover **xvalues** too.
(*prvalues* could be replaced back to simple **rvalues** in symmetry with how **lvalues** are defined)

```
      expression
      /        \
   glvalue    grvalue
   /     \    /     \
lvalue   xvalue   rvalue
```

[Value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) can be defined more simple:

- an **lvalue** has *identity* but cannot be moved from; is a glvalue that is not an xvalue
- an **rvalue** has no identity but can be *moved from*; is a grvalue that is not an xvalue
- an **xvalue** has *identity* and can be *moved from*.

> Every expression is either an **lvalue**, **xvalue** or **rvalue**.

Comment: I think your approach is circular. "Moving from" isn't a fundamental notion, but rather, a library convention *built* on the current type system and object model. Lvalues and rvalues are made precisely to allow lvalue and rvalue references.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of rvalues was made more general, and the essence of rvalues was identified to be the absence of aliasing. A new value category, xvalues, was added that shares this property, and the subset of rvalues that was present prior to C++11 was renamed to prvalues ("pure rvalues").

The two primary divisions we want are now these:

- glvalue vs prvalue: glvalues are objects (= storage locations); prvalues are the traditional "temporaries" (but see below).
- lvalue vs rvalue: lvalues bind to lvalue references, rvalues bind to rvalue references. This distinction is the one needed to define how references and reference binding works.

An xvalue is both a glvalue and an rvalue. This reflects the fact that rvalue references are a way to perform lvalue-to-xvalue conversion (via cast, `std::move`), that is, to have *user-defined rvalues*. They also allow a conversion in the other direction, of prvalue to lvalue, by binding an rvalue to an rvalue reference (which is now an lvalue).

C++17 refines the idea a bit further by turning prvalues into "notional values" or "unmaterialized values" which are no longer objects. In this new picture, only glvalues are objects. Prvalues, however, can be *materialized* into objects, which is appropriately called "prvalue-to-glvalue conversion".

This new way of thinking about value categories means that if you have a function `T f();`, where `T` is not a reference, then the expression `f()` itself is not an object (hence does not necessitate copying of objects!), but when needed (e.g. if you say `f().x`), the an object is created and initialized with the prvalue (= materialized) so as to allow the member access.

---

Maybe it's valuable to summarize all the conversions that exist in C++17:

- "glvalue-to-prvalue": This is what C calls the "lvalue conversion". Example: `int a = 1; 1 + a;` The second operand the addition expression is a prvalue, obtained by glvalue-to-prvalue conversion of `a`.
- "rvalue-to-lvalue": Provided by rvalue references. Example: `int && r = e`. Here `e` is an rvalue expression, and `r` is an lvalue designating the same (or potentially materialized) object.
- "prvalue-to-glvalue": This is materialization of a prvalue were a glvalue is expected.
- "lvalue-to-rvalue": Only actually available as "lvalue-to-xvalue" via `std::move`, e.g. `int a; static_cast<int&&>(a);`.

Note that all the pairs that appear in the list have the same number of letters -- either both have one letter, or both have two. I think that's a consequence of the well-chosen taxonomy that your proposed alternative lacks.

Comment: From n3055 "II. Overview of Changes", page 3:

Rvalues, as currently known in the core language clauses, are renamed to “prvalues” (“pure” rvalues).

Comment: @mteodor: OK, fair enough, I changed that.